# Method setUp in android.test.AndroidTestCase not mocked

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I'm trying to come to terms with the new unit test feature of Android Studio. 
I've followed the instructions on http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support. The description there explicitly mentions the 'Method ... not mocked' error and suggests to put the following into the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

This works in so far as the tests run when started from the command line with

```
gradlew test --continue
```

but not when I run the test class from Android Studio with rightclick -> run. This way, I get the same error again:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setUp in android.test.AndroidTestCase not mocked. See https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support for details.
    at android.test.AndroidTestCase.setUp(AndroidTestCase.java)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT: The content of the test class doesn't really matter because the setUp of the test fails, I tried with the most simple class:

```
public class ContactFormToolTest extends AndroidTestCase {    

    public void testSOmething(){
        assertEquals(false, true);
    }            
}
```

Also tried overriding setUp, makes no difference.

Comment: could you add the code of your test class?

Comment: See edit in question.

Comment: I had a very similar output, which was solved this way: Create a fresh new android project with a MainActivity. Open the MainActivity. Put the cursor on "MainActivity" in the class definition. Right-click and select GoTo => Test. Create a new test file with the suggested paramteres. Try to run a simple test. If this works copy all your files into this new project. Ugly, but it worked for me. Guess there was some little setting I missed.

Comment: if setUp fails so maybe add setUp code?

Comment: It doesn't fail, it's not even executed. Same happens when setUp is empty.

Comment: @Ascorbin Didn't you ask this question already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new `Unit Tests` feature in Android Studio *fakes the entire Android SDK* so that you can run fast, Java-only tests, without needing to install your application on an Android device (this is similar to Robolectric).  The general idea is that you mock all the responses from the Android SDK calls.

`AndroidTestCase` is used to run a test with the *real* Android SDK.

So, your issue is that you are trying to run an `AndroidTestCase` that depends on the Android SDK, but your test runner is launching the `Unit Tests` environment, which uses a fake Android SDK instead of a real one.

You need to choose one approach.  If you want a pure unit test, then you probably should use a JUnit 4 test class instead of an AndroidTestCase.  More instructions here:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#build

Comment: Couldn't this test bet moved to **androidTest** package?

Comment: Does new Android Studio unit test feature make Robolectric superfluous then?

Answer (score 13):

From: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain
>   any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real
>   devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is
>   to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on
>   any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not
>   explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito). If that proves problematic, you
>   can add the snippet below to your build.gradle to change this
>   behavior:

```
android {

   // ...   

  testOptions { 
      unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true   
  } 
}
```

Comment: What does this do, add real implementations to android.jar?

Comment: My guess is that each method of android.jar returns some default (dummy) value just so the tests can run

Answer (score 3):

As of SDK version 24, [AndroidTestCase is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)

> **This class was deprecated in API level 24.**
>
> Use InstrumentationRegistry instead. New tests should be written using
>   the [Android Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html).

You are supposed to use the Espresso framework for UI testing. There is [a tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html).